How to manipulate a list of PDA in anchor
I have a smart contract i am working with, in the acceptOffer function, i need to invalidate all previous Offer, by using isAccepted(boolean) back to false,I have search online looking for a way to get it working, and also tried
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction()]
pub struct AcceptOffer<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [USER_TAG,authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        has_one = authority
    )]
    pub user: Box<Account<'info, User>>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub offer: Box<Account<'info, Offer>>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub previous_offers: Box<Account<'info, Offer>>, // added this line
    #[account(mut)]
    pub request: Box<Account<'info, Request>>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

but i get error proc-macro panicked: Invariant violation: composite constraints can only be raw or literals
this are my code snippet,the commented section is what I am trying to achieve
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction()]
pub struct AcceptOffer<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [USER_TAG,authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        has_one = authority
    )]
    pub user: Box<Account<'info, User>>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub offer: Box<Account<'info, Offer>>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub request: Box<Account<'info, Request>>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}




    pub fn accept_offer(ctx: Context<AcceptOffer>) -> Result<()> {
        let user = &mut ctx.accounts.user;
        let offer = &mut ctx.accounts.offer;
        let request = &mut ctx.accounts.request;

        if user.account_type != AccountType::Buyer {
            return err!(MarketplaceError::OnlyBuyersAllowed);
        }

        if request.buyer_id != user.id {
            return err!(MarketplaceError::UnauthorizedBuyer);
        }

        if offer.is_accepted {
            return err!(MarketplaceError::OfferAlreadyAccepted);
        }

        if Clock::get().unwrap().unix_timestamp as u64 > request.updated_at + TIME_TO_LOCK
            && request.lifecycle == RequestLifecycle::AcceptedByBuyer
        {
            return err!(MarketplaceError::RequestLocked);
        }

        //TODO: fix this reset

        // for prev_offer_id in request.offer_ids.iter() {
        //     // let previous_offer = &mut ctx.accounts.offers[*prev_offer_id as usize];
        //     // previous_offer.is_accepted = false;
        //     // emit!(OfferAccepted {
        //     //     offer_id: previous_offer.id,
        //     //     buyer_address: *ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info().key,
        //     //     is_accepted: false,
        //     // });
        // }

        offer.is_accepted = true;
        offer.updated_at = Clock::get().unwrap().unix_timestamp as u64;
        request.offer_ids.push(offer.id);
        request.locked_seller_id = offer.seller_id;
        request.sellers_price_quote = offer.price;
        request.lifecycle = RequestLifecycle::AcceptedByBuyer;
        request.updated_at = Clock::get().unwrap().unix_timestamp as u64;

        emit!(RequestAccepted {
            request_id: request.id,
            offer_id: offer.id,
            seller_id: offer.seller_id,
            updated_at: request.updated_at,
            sellers_price_quote: request.sellers_price_quote,
        });

        emit!(OfferAccepted {
            offer_id: offer.id,
            buyer_address: *ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info().key,
            is_accepted: true,
        });

        Ok(())
    }


#[account]
pub struct Offer {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub id: u64,
    pub request_id: u64,
    pub price: i64,
    pub images: Vec<String>,
    pub store_name: String,
    pub seller_id: u64,
    pub is_accepted: bool,
    pub created_at: u64,
    pub updated_at: u64,
}


#[account]
pub struct Request {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub id: u64,
    pub name: String,
    pub buyer_id: u64,
    pub description: String,
    pub images: Vec<String>,
    pub sellers_price_quote: i64,
    pub seller_ids: Vec<u64>,
    pub offer_ids: Vec<u64>,
    pub locked_seller_id: u64,
    pub location: Location,
    pub created_at: u64,
    pub updated_at: u64,
    pub lifecycle: RequestLifecycle,
}

#[account]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct User {
    pub id: u64,
    pub username: String,
    pub phone: String,
    pub location: Location,
    pub created_at: i64,
    pub updated_at: i64,
    pub account_type: AccountType,
    pub authority: Pubkey,
}



The error proc-macro panicked: Invariant violation: composite constraints can only be raw or literals talks about the limitation of the Anchor framework.
As of now (I believe with current Anchor version 0.30.*) it's not possible to use/link the Rust constant in the #account macro to be part of the seeds.
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [USER_TAG,authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        has_one = authority
    )]

instead, you need to "hard code" (and possibly duplicate) the seed string into the macro directly
seeds = [b"user-tag", authority.key().as_ref()],

